# Bootstrap: 2 popovers on a page, only 1 is working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, popover

I mention the 2 on a page part because if one is working, then the JS to initialize it must be working. FWIW just in case, I have tried to add the initializer code right above the popover append in the JS to no effect.

**Not working popover**

HTML generated:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign question-icon cursor-point" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="An initial deposit (calculated per item) is required if your trip is longer than 14 days or if any of your rental dates overlap Burning Man. This deposiit will be refunded in accordance with our Terms of Service" tabindex="0"></span>
```

By JS dynamically like so:

```
$(some_element).append('<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign question-icon cursor-point" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="An initial deposit (calculated per item) is required if your trip is longer than 14 days or if any of your rental dates overlap Burning Man. This deposiit will be refunded in accordance with our Terms of Service" tabIndex="0"></span></td>')
```

**Working popover**

Generated HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 cloudinary-div text-center" style="height: 150px" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Example shown: RED Avid helmet." tabindex="0" data-original-title="" title="">
```

From view file like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 cloudinary-div text-center" style="height: 150px" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="<%= i.description %>" tabindex="0">
```

---

It seems to me based on the generated HTML, the only difference is that the working one has `data-original-title=""` and `title=""`. But adding this to the non-working one has not helped.

You can see it on the live site: www.lastmingear.com/request
 - On the left of the screen, click any category, and then items will pop up. Click any item to see the popover that WORKS. 
 - To see the non-working popover, change the dates of request to be longer than 14 days, on the right hand cart table, you'll see a line item for Refundable Deposit. Next to that line item is a question mark icon. That's the popover. Clicking it doesn't' do anything

Comment: can you post your popover initialisation code?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're calling .popover() before your new span is added to the page. You'll need to call .popover() again after you've attached your new span to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Clayton was right about `popover` being called before the new span being added. But in my code, calling it after it's added every single time would be a bit ugly, so instead, I just added this function to initialize `popover` on click.

```
$(document).on('click','[data-toggle="popover"]', function() {
  $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
    container: 'body'
  });
})
```

OK spoke a little too soon, the answer above works ONLY if you click somewhere besides the popover and THEN click the popover. Now... obviously the reason would seem to be that the first time it's clicked it calls the initialize function, but then can't activate it immediately, and therefore the second time it's clicked it works. EXCEPT that the originally working popover works the first time on click, the originally non-working popover requires the double click.

In the meantime, since there's not really an issue with speed on my really simple site, I'm just using the below, because basically any element with a popover is only reachable on my site via a click somewhere on the page:

```
$(document).on('click',  function() {
  $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover({
    container: 'body'
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a long time ago but I have come down to this *popover* issue too. My problem situation is a bit different though but it may be helpful for other people.

In my situation, I am initialising popover when DOM is ready as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
         placement: 'top',
         container: 'body'
      });
    });
```

I am using *datatables* in my main table which has *several pages* - All popovers within the `buttons` that appear in the first page work perfect. Now, when I move to other pages, the popovers in these rows do not work. I believe that datatables remove non-visible rows from the DOM and the popover initialisation happens (code block above) when the DOM is *ready* only for the visible rows - Leaving the non-visible ones in the other table pages without initialisation for their popovers.

Having this problem I first thought in initialising the popover (as in code block above) every time a different page number of the table was clicked - In this way, every popover would always work. However, the issue with this is that this was not going to be bulletproof since in datatables, there can be a situation in which a data row in the page 8 (in which I have not clicked, therefore popover is not initialised for that page rows) can directly come to page 1 because a filtering through any column of the table header.

Also, after this, I was using @James's block of code, in which I needed to click twice in order for the popup to work, which is also a solution but it was not feasible for my situation.

My popovers react when being *clicked and not hovered* therefore I thought in the following solution (is not really efficient but it was the only way it would work in my situation) - As webpage's users click in the button to get the popover, I just thought in the previous event that happens before clicking, which in this case would be *onmouseover*. In this way, every time an user would retrieve a data row, no matter when the button popover was added, it will always be initialised just before being clicked.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', "[data-toggle='popover']", function (event) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement: 'top',
        container: 'body'
    });
});
```

Please note that in this way, using this last block of code, is useless to also initialise the popover when on the ready event of the DOM (first block of code).